# What is the reason to call a program with set -- env

Tags: shell-script, shell, set

I've seen that some code in bash scripts calls a programm with `set -- env` preceding actual command, e.g.:

```
set -- env GOPATH=/some/path go build ${PACKAGE}
```

what is the reason to do it? Isn't it the same as just

```
env GOPATH=/some/path go build ${PACKAGE}
```

Comment: Where have you seen that? It doesn't seem too useful unless there's something like `set -- "$@" "$optional_argument"` afterwards.

Comment: There are a lot of places in Gentoo ebuild eclasses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set -- env GOPATH=/some/path go build ${PACKAGE}
```

This calls no program (well, it calls the built-in `set`, but not `env` or `go`).  It sets the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc., collectively the list `"$@"`) to the words after `--` so that, if `$PACKAGE` is the string `hello world` you have

```
$ PACKAGE='hello world'
$ set -- env GOPATH=/some/path go build ${PACKAGE}
$ i=1; for param in "$@"; do printf '$%d = "%s"\n' "$i" "$param"; i=$((i+1)); done
$1 = "env"
$2 = "GOPATH=/some/path"
$3 = "go"
$4 = "build"
$5 = "hello"
$6 = "world"
```

I.e., it sets the parameters `$1` through to `$6` to the values after `--`, and it won't execute `env` or `go`.

If one were to then say

```
"$@"
```

*this* would execute the command.  `"$@"` expands to the positional parameters (individually quoted).

In e.g. `bash`, it would be equivalent of setting the values of a named array:

```
array=( env GOPATH=/some/path go build ${PACKAGE} )
```

This also does not execute `env` or `go`.

Later, using

```
"${array[@]}"
```

would execute that command line.

Note that the double quoting in `"$@"` and `"${array[@]}"` is intentional and important. Without the double quotes, the elements of these lists would be split on whitespace into separate words (just as the string `hello world` was split into two when using `${PACKAGE}` unquoted above), and the shell would additionally perform filename globbing on the generated words.